# Validate object against xsd / generated object

Tags: java, validation, xsd, jaxb, jax-rs

I have an application where I have generated Java classes from an xsd schema. I also have a rest service using jax-rs. I need to validate the input to the POST methods, to ensure that comply with the rules set in the xsd schema.

```
@POST
@Path("/person/add")
public void addPerson(Person person) {

    //Need to validate Person object 

    daoManager.addPersonToDB(person);
}
```

The Person object is a class generated from the xsd. Can I assume that the object complies with the xsd, or will I have to validate the object? In that case, how can I validate?

I know this is a newbie question, but I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried myself, but I think the following code would work.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
```

according to your namespace, use

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "yourXSD.xsd");
```

or

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "yourXSD.xsd");
```

and then marshal the person instance, if no exception, that means the person instance is fine. Otherwise, it's not.

---

Oh, I forgot on thing. Before you marshal it, remember to setSchema()

```
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("your.xsd"));

    marshaller.setSchema(schema);
    marshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
      public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        return false; //to stop the marshal if anything happened
      }
    });
```

Comment: There is another article that might help you. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/UseMarshalValidation.htm